# Condition based regex needed to match a particular content

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Ex.    `string1 string2 content abc`

i want to select `content abc` from above content, i have used

> (?<=string1( string2)).*

But sometimes string2 will not present in the whole content. i used this

> (?<=string1).*

Content may come randomly and i need a single regex to march the content if string2 comes or not. 
I tried this which is **not working**

> **(?<=string1( string2)).*|(?<=string1).***

Comment: What are those redundant colons? Requirements are not clear.

Comment: Whatever you're implying by it, it doesn't exist in sample input. So it never matches.

Comment: Kindly check now

Comment: Isn't this enough `(?<=string2).*`? Live demo https://regex101.com/r/ksVKM3/1

Comment: Nope. some times `string2` will not be present. suggest me for this case https://regex101.com/r/ksVKM3/2

Comment: Use this `string1(?: string2)?(.*)` then access to first capturing group https://regex101.com/r/qfIhSG/1/

Comment: Can you please post a few examples with the wanted result? what is "content"? Are "string1/2" always the same?

Comment: Yes, and if `string1` is not always there use `(?m)^.*(?<=string2|string1)(.*)`. What you want is in first capturing group.

Comment: yes it is a good idea but my case i can run only one regex and will be applied some generic code which will return the match found

Comment: Are you matching from string2 to the end of line?

Comment: Not from string2 . i want to n skip string1 and string2(if it is presents)

Comment: What would be expected output for `a string1 b string2 c`?

Comment: Is it PCRE? Try [`string1(?:\s+string2)?\s*\K.*`](https://regex101.com/r/03SEqM/2)

Comment: No. it is java regex engine @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Try [`(?<=string1(?! string2)|string1 string2).*`](https://regex101.com/r/0BSfwl/1) then

Comment: Why I thought it is python...

Comment: `c` @revo2 But ma case no ohter strings will come . `string1 string2 content` or `string1 content`

Comment: Thanks it works @WiktorStribiżew Could you pls explain the regex

Comment: `(?<=string1 (?!string2 )).*|(?<=string1 string2 ).*`

Answer (score 1):

Using Java variable lookbehinds you are able to do this which you shouldn't try on online regex testers that doesn't support Java:

```
(?<=\bstring2\b|\bstring1\b(?!.{0,999999}\bstring2\b)).*
```

The order of words are important. This matches following strings:

```
string1 string2 abc
               ^^^^
```

```
string1 abc
       ^^^^
```

```
string2 abc
       ^^^^
```

**Note**: **If you don't want to match latter you may go with [@Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49776972/1020526).**

Breakdown:

- `(?<=` Start a positive lookbehind

  - `\bstring2\b` Match word `string2`
  - `|` Or
  - `\bstring1\b` Match word `string1`
  - `(?!.{0,999999}\bstring2\b)` That doesn't precede word `string2`
- `)` End of PL
- `.*` Match up to end of line

Comment: You may use [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) to show case the pattern.

Comment: I'm aware of online regex testers that support Java. I just don't like them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `(?<=string1( string2)).*|(?<=string1).*` fails to match the `string1 string2 content abc` string correctly because the engine, while analyzing the string from left to right, matches the location after `string1` with the second alternative (`(?<=string1).*`).

The regex you may use is

```
(?<=string1(?! string2)|string1 string2).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0BSfwl/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=string1(?! string2)|string1 string2)` - is a positive lookbehind that requires the presence of `string1` not followed with a space and `string2` or `string1 string2`
- `.*` - matches 0+ chars other than line break chars.

Use `\b` word boundaries round `stringX` in case you plan to match whole words (remember to double backslashes in a Java string literal).